# Random 2D array without specifying min and max

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, integer

In Python, is there a way to generate a 2d array using `numpy` with random integer entries without specifying either the low or high?

I tried `mat = np.random.randint(size=(3, 4))` but it did not work.

Comment: No, it's mathematically impossible to create a random number generator with uniform distribution for the range (-inf, inf) but it's possible with other distributions. You could use a normal distribution and round the values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to specify the min or max values of the array, one can use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

```
np.random.normal(mean, standard deviation, (rows,columns))
```

And then round it with [`astype(np.int)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), as

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mat = (np.random.normal(1, 3, (3,4))).astype(np.int)
[[ 0  0  0 -1]
[ 0  5  0  0]
[-5  1  2  2]]
```

Please note that the output may vary, as the values are random.

---

If you want to specify the min and max values, there are various ways of doing that, such as

```
mat = (np.random.random((3,4))*10).astype(np.int) # Random ints between 0 and 10
```

or

```
mat = np.random.randint(1,5, size=(3,4)) # Random ints between 1 and 5
```

And more.

Comment: I don't get it. OP asks for _"integer entries without specifying either of low or high"_ and you are providing one solution with decimals and two solutions with specifying low and high.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The first one only had decimals because I forgot to add the `astype(int)`, but then corrected it. The options with min and max are a plus that may help those that come across the answer and don't have that constraint.